# Move rig bone in edit mode bugged

Tags: rigging

[video about rigging issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BGrbcEZCrQ&feature=youtu.be)

Why does this happen? I'm only moving the bone on the z axis but it moves to the side also.

Comment: Looks like you have snapping to the mesh turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured it out myself, had snapping to closest face enabled.